# Async function triggers twice - angular firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that

1. Uses auth service to get status and email of current logged in user.
2. Uses userService that talks to firestore users collection to retrieve all users then assign current logged in user to a User variable based on the email.
3. Uses cartService that talks to a collection nested inside 'users' collection to get the loggedInUser's cart collection.
4. Uses the cartService again after retrieving a specific cart object that needs to be passed in a method to retrieve all products from a specific cart.
5. Uses a productService to delete a specific product from the previously retrieved cart.

The problem i am having is that the entire method call is being called twice when i click the button. Attached is the HTML code for the button plus the entire function itself.

```
<table *ngIf="myCartProducts?.length > 0" class="table table-responsive-sm">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let product of myCartProducts">
        <td>
          {{ product.name }} 
          <br> 
          {{product.description}}
          <br>
          {{product.size}}
          <br>
          <img height="50px;width:50px" src="{{product.img1}}">

        </td>
        <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
        <td><a routerLink="/cartproduct/{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> Details</a></td>
        <td><a style="color:white;" id="{{product.id}}" (click)="removeFromCart($event)" class="btn btn-danger "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</a></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

//FUNCTION

```
removeFromCart(event){
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;


    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.loggedInUser = auth.email;

        this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
          this.allUsers = users;
          this.myUser = this.allUsers.filter(user => user.email == this.loggedInUser)
          //  console.log(this.myUser);
          this.currentUser = this.myUser[0];

          this.cartService.getCarts(this.currentUser).subscribe(carts => {
            this.allCarts = carts;
            this.mycart = this.allCarts[0];
            console.log(this.mycart);

            this.cartService.getCartProduct(target.id,this.currentUser,this.mycart).subscribe(product =>{
              this.productToDelete = product;

              console.log(this.productToDelete);

              this.productService.deleteProductFromCart(this.productToDelete,this.currentUser, this.mycart);

            });



          });





        });

      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });

  }
```

The function works just fine but triggers twice and that increases my calls to firebase which i want to avoid. Please let me know what i am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure it is the whole "removeFromCart" method that is being called twice or it is just some subscribe part that is called twice.

Comment: it seems like the line "console.log(this.productToDelete);" is what triggers twice inside the getCartProduct method subscription. I removed all other console.logs from my init method and did a log('instantiate') to check whether its accidentally instantiating the ngOnInit again or not and seems like its not. So i think its just that specific subscription which gives an error the 2nd time because the product is already deleted from the cart.